# add_custom_command for copy *.y to *.txt file

Tags: cmake, ctest, cmake-custom-command, cmake-modules

I am trying to copy the generated `*.y` output (plane luma values, no header info) to text file using the `add_custom_command` CMake command. How can I add the `copy` command in `add_custom_command`?

I want to redirect the generated `*.y` output to text file. But the `>` redirection was not running directly in CMake without `add_custom_command`, so I tried to use `add_custom_command`. Here I thought to use `copy` instead of `>`, 
but still in both cases I am not able to redirect or copy the `*.y` output to `*.txt` file.

```
macro(COMPARE file function type type_out)
  get_filename_component(main_base_name ${file} NAME_WE)
  set(main_base_name_mangled ${main_base_name}_${function}_${type_out})

  # file generated by simulation
  set(output_file ${function}_${type_out}_0_opt.y)
  # reference file generated by generator
  set(reference_file ${function}_${type_out}_0_ref.y)

  set(output_file_txt ${function}_${type_out}_0_opt.txt)
  set(reference_file_txt ${function}_${type_out}_0_ref.txt)

  add_custom_target(compare_${main_base_name_mangled}
    COMMAND cmp ${reference_file} ${output_file}
   COMMENT "Comparing ${reference_file} ${output_file}")

  add_dependencies(compare_${main_base_name_mangled}
    simulate_${main_base_name_mangled})

  add_test(NAME Compare_${main_base_name_mangled}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
                             --target compare_${main_base_name_mangled})

  # add dependency to compile first
  set_tests_properties(Compare_${main_base_name_mangled}
    PROPERTIES REQUIRED_FILES ${reference_file})
  set_tests_properties(Compare_${main_base_name_mangled}
    PROPERTIES REQUIRED_FILES  ${output_file})
  # test Compare_X depends on Simulate_X
  set_tests_properties(Compare_${main_base_name_mangled}
    PROPERTIES DEPENDS Simulate_${base_name_mangled})

  #Here I have added my code to redirect my *.y output to *.txt file  
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${output_file} 
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${output_file} ${output_file_txt}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${output_file} 
    COMMENT "Redirecting ${output_file} to ${output_file_txt}")

  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${reference_file}
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${reference_file} ${reference_file_txt}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${reference_file}
    COMMENT "Redirecting ${reference_file} to ${reference_file_txt}")
endmacro()
```

After running this code, I want to generate two text files, which is still not possible with above CMake changes.

Comment: The `OUTPUT` directive of `add_custom_command` should specify the file *produced by* the custom command (i.e. the output file), not the input file.

Answer (score 0):

The `OUTPUT` directive in your `add_custom_command` calls should specify the file *produced by* the custom command (i.e. the output file), instead of the input file. Here is the fixed snippet from your code:

```
  # Here I have added my code to redirect my *.y output to *.txt file  
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${output_file_txt} 
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${output_file} ${output_file_txt}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${output_file} 
    COMMENT "Redirecting ${output_file} to ${output_file_txt}")

  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${reference_file_txt}
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${reference_file} ${reference_file_txt}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${reference_file}
    COMMENT "Redirecting ${reference_file} to ${reference_file_txt}")
```